# Different servers for mail and hosting

Tags: email, email-server, mx-record

I've website on MS Azure and and a mail server from a different company. Two servers and their IP adresses are different. I am trying to host my website on MS Azure and receive/send e-mails using my mail server. Website is working fine but I cannot receive e-mails. This is how my domain configuration looks like:

```
mail.domain.com     A   [mail server IP]    
domain.com  CNAME   address.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com   
www.domain.com  CNAME   domain.com  
*.domain.com    MX  0,mail.domain.com   
domain.com  MX  10,mail.domain.com  
domain.com  NS  eu.dnsenable.com    
domain.com  NS  tr.dnsenable.com    
domain.com  NS  us.dnsenable.com
```

I guess I couldn't configure MX records correctly. I can't receive or send e-mails.

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts